# Image sensor linear matrix coefficients (color reproduction), how are they applied?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have some raw images to debayer then apply colour corrections/transforms to.  I use OpenCV and C++, and for the image sensor used the linear matrix coefficients are:

1.32         -0.46        0.14

-0.36         1.25        0.11

0.08        -1.96        1.88

I am not sure how to apply these to the image.  It's not clear to me what I am supposed to do with them and why.

Can anyone explain what these colour reproduction or colour matrix values are, and how to use them to process an image?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear because it seems you also don't know what to do.

> "what I am supposed to do with them"

First thing coming to my mind, you can convolve image with that matrix by using [filter2D](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga27c049795ce870216ddfb366086b5a04). According to documentation `filter2D`:

> Convolves an image with the kernel.
>
> The function applies an arbitrary linear filter to an image. In-place
> operation is supported. When the aperture is partially outside the
> image, the function interpolates outlier pixel values according to the
> specified border mode.

Here is the example code snippet hpw tp use it:

```
Mat output;
Mat kernelMatrix = (Mat_<double>(3, 3) << 1.32, -0.46, 0.14,
                         -0.36, 1.25, 0.11,
                         0.08, -1.96, 1.88);
filter2D(rawImage, output, -1, kernelMatrix);
```

Comment: This answer is fundamentally wrong. Should be removed.

Comment: When people see something first time in their life, they try to make it similar to something they seen before. This is human nature

Comment: That's fine, but leaving a wrong answer up (especially an accepted one, which shows up prominently in search) does a disservice to the community. That's why I recommend deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

Before debayering you have an array B (-ayer) of MxN filtered "graylevel" values. They are physically filtered in the sense that the the number of photons measured by each one of them is affected by the color filter on top of each sensor site.

After debayering you have an array C (-olor) of MxNx3 BGR values, obtained by (essentially) reindexing the B array. However, each of the 3 values at a (row, col) image location represents 3 physical measurements. This is not the final image because we still need to "convert" the physical measurements to numbers that are representative of color channels *as perceived by a human* (or, more generally, by the intended user, which could also be some kind of image processing software). That is, the physical values need to be mapped to a color space.

The 3x3 "color correction" matrix you have represents one possible mapping - a simple linear one. You need to apply it in turn to each BGR triple at all (row, col) pixel locations. For example (in python/numpy/cv2):

```
import numpy as np

def colorCorrect(img, M):
  """Applies a color correction M to a BGR image img"""
  rows, cols, depth = img.shape
  assert depth == 3
  assert M.shape == (3, 3)
  img_corr = np.zeros((rows, cols, 3), dtype=img.dtype)
  for r in range(rows):
    for c in range(cols):
      img_corr[r, c, :] = M.dot(img[r, c, :])
  return img_corr
```

Comment: Sow how is the colour correction applied?  For instance what do the colour correction values represent and are they added to a pixel, multiplied, or what?  This is what I have been struggling with.  I can't find how to apply this matrix of values to the image to achieve the colour correction.  I'm not sure what the code is doing here... possibly add some comments to the for loops please?  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Look at the code in my answer: that "M.dot(img[r, c, :])" is a matrix-vector multiplication. The output red is the dot product of the first row of M times the input RGB (debayered) triple, the output green is the dot product of the second row of M times the input RGB, etc. 
If you are asking how one find the values of M, that's a completely separate question - look for camera color calibration, "Macbeth chart", etc.